# How to have an 'EditText' element deselect itself when 'enter' is pressed

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm making an android application and I have an EditText element where, once you press enter in that field, text elsewhere on the same page is updated, though you cannot immediately see it because the keyboard is in the way. In short, is there a way to have the keyboard go away (i.e. have the text editor de-select itself when enter is pressed)?

Comment: You want the keyboard to disappear when you finish entering the text in `EditText`?

Comment: If your main problem is hiding the soft keyboard, check out this [question thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to set your `EditText` as singleLine and enable the `IMEAction` Done, like this:

```
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeActionLabel="Done"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```